# Laravel blade template not rendering with slug

Tags: templates, laravel, routes, laravel-blade, slug

Hi maybe I am missing something here however if I use a route such as

> /admin-user-management

Then the blade template renders correctly. However using the exact code, copy/pasted into another view with the route

> /admin/{id}

Then the view does not render the template.

Both views are identical in every single way, one renders the view correctly with the template while the other one with a slug will not render the template correctly, it will spit out elements at random however it does not render the actual layout correctly.

Why would they be different? This is not the first time I've come across this either and I'm just stumped as to what the difference would be if a slug is in the URL or not.

Once again, both files are identical.

One is the useraccounts function, the other is the show function on the controller.

```
public function show($id)
{
    $user=User::find($id);
    return view('admin.show',compact('user'));
}

public function useraccounts()
{
    $users = User::all();
    return view('admin.useraccounts', compact('users'));
}
```

And the button that displays the user details is as follows

```
<a href="{{route('admin.show',$user)}}" class="btn btn-primary">View all information</a>
```

Please does anyone have any ideas about this issue I am having?

---

The admin.show view

```
@extends('admin')

@section('main')
    <aside class="right-side">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <section class="content-header">
            <h1>
                Dashboard
                <small>Control panel</small>
            </h1>
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="/admin"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
                <li class="active">Dashboard</li>
            </ol>
        </section>

        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">

            <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                    <!-- small box -->
                    <div class="small-box bg-green">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <h3>
                                {{--53<sup style="font-size: 20px">%</sup>--}}
                            </h3>
                            <p>
                                Statistics
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="icon">
                            <i class="ion ion-stats-bars"></i>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">
                            View Information <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- ./col -->
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                    <!-- small box -->
                    <div class="small-box bg-yellow">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <h3>
                                {{--53--}}
                            </h3>
                            <p>
                                User Management
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="icon">
                            <i class="ion ion-person-add"></i>
                        </div>
                        <a href="/admin-user-management" class="small-box-footer">
                            Edit Details <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- ./col -->
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                    <!-- small box -->
                    <div class="small-box bg-red">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <h3>
                                {{--65--}}
                            </h3>
                            <p>
                                Detailed Site Information
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="icon">
                            <i class="ion ion-pie-graph"></i>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">
                            View Data <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- ./col -->
            </div><!-- /.row -->

            <!-- top row -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 connectedSortable">

                </div><!-- /.col -->
            </div>

        </section><!-- /.content -->
        <label>{{$user->name}}</label>
    </aside><!-- /.right-side -->
@endsection
```

And then the admin.admin-user-management view which is using

```
@extends('admin')

@section('main')
    <aside class="right-side">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <section class="content-header">
            <h1>
                Dashboard
                <small>Control panel</small>
            </h1>
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="/admin"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
                <li class="active">Dashboard</li>
            </ol>
        </section>

        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">

            <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                    <!-- small box -->
                    <div class="small-box bg-green">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <h3>
                                {{--53<sup style="font-size: 20px">%</sup>--}}
                            </h3>
                            <p>
                                Statistics
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="icon">
                            <i class="ion ion-stats-bars"></i>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">
                            View Information <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- ./col -->
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                    <!-- small box -->
                    <div class="small-box bg-yellow">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <h3>
                                {{--53--}}
                            </h3>
                            <p>
                                User Management
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="icon">
                            <i class="ion ion-person-add"></i>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">
                            Edit Details <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- ./col -->
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                    <!-- small box -->
                    <div class="small-box bg-red">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <h3>
                                {{--65--}}
                            </h3>
                            <p>
                                Detailed Site Information
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="icon">
                            <i class="ion ion-pie-graph"></i>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">
                            View Data <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- ./col -->
            </div><!-- /.row -->

            <!-- top row -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 connectedSortable">

                </div><!-- /.col -->
            </div>

        </section><!-- /.content -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="form-box">

                @if (session('message'))
                    <div class="alert alert-info" style="text-align: center; width: 200px; ">
                        {{ session('message') }}
                    </div>
                @endif

                <div class="container">

                    {{-- @if(Auth::user()) --}}
                    <form class="form-group">
                        @if($users != null)
                            @foreach($users as $user)
                                @if($user->admin != 'true')
                                    {!! Form::label($user->name) !!}
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <br>
                                        <a href="{{route('admin.show', ['id' => $user->id])}}" class="btn btn-primary">View all information</a>
                                    </div>
                                    </br>
                                    <div class="container">
                                        {{-- <a href="{{route('house.edit',$house)}}" class="btn btn-primary">Update house details</a> --}}
                                    </div>
                                    <br>

                                    <div class="container">
                                        {{-- {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route'=>['house.destroy', $house->id]]) !!} --}}
                                        {{-- {!! Form::submit('Delete House', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!} --}}
                                        {{-- {!! Form::close() !!} --}}
                                    </div>
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
                        @else
                            {{-- <li><a href={{url('/house/create')}}>Add new house</a></li> --}}
                        @endif
                    </form>
                    {{-- @endif --}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aside><!-- /.right-side -->
@endsection
```

The routes.php file

```
//Admin Routes

Route::get('/admin-user-management', 'AdminController@useraccounts');
Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');
```

Header

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Admin | Dashboard</title>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>
    <!-- bootstrap 3.0.2 -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- font Awesome -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Morris chart -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/morris/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- jvectormap -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- fullCalendar -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Daterange picker -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- bootstrap wysihtml5 - text editor -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/AdminLTE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Comment: Would you share the header part where you contained the css stylesheets

Comment: I added the information for the header however as I mentioned, even if the code is duplicated, only one renders correctly while the other does not, so I think in a way the header information is irrelevant but if it does help, then I have added it :)

Comment: Let me guess, the css files are placed at public/admin/bootstrap ?

Comment: Yes that is correct :) It seemed to be a problem in the paths.

Comment: Glad to help, if you like I can add that an answer, for the community benefit.

Comment: Sure! Feel free to do so, I am sure I'm not the only one who did such a simple yet silly mistake.

Comment: I see you have accepted another answer, so it's OK :-) great it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your asset paths are relative, they should be absolute:

```
<link href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Notice the extra `/` before `bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css`. If the `/` is missing and your URL is `/admin/1`, the relative path is `/admin`, and it will try to find the bootstrap CSS file in `/admin/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css` which if course doesn't exist.

---

The best solution here is to use the [`asset`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#urls) helper function when generating any asset URLs, because it will generate a complete URL including the protocol and domain, which would avoid any such issues in the future, like so:

```
<link href="{{ asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The `asset` function will generate the URL like so:

```
http://example.com/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

This will mean the location will always be correct. Of course you should use the function when loading all assets from your server, including JavaScript files, but not on external resources like `html5shiv`, which is loaded from `maxcdn.com`.

Comment: Hi, if I use data dump it seems either way spits out the correct information, so wouldn't that just be an alternative way to achieve the same result as using

    <a href="{{route('admin.show',$user)}}" class="btn btn-primary">View all information</a>

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your problem, are you saying that the `admin.show` view is rendered incorrectly? If so, please include the view code.

Comment: I don't have any issues retrieving the actual data itself, however when I try to render the view it only works without a slug. Once a slug is added the template does not render at all.

Comment: By slug you are referring to the `{id}` parameter? So it works for when accessing `/admin` but not `/admin/1` where `1` would be the user id.

Comment: Yes that is correct, that is the frustrating problem. Without the slug it extends the template correctly, when I add the slug then it refuses to render correctly.

Comment: Could you please also include the entire route definition for the two routes.

Comment: Modified the answer with the solution